# Disable DDE warning

Tags: excel, vba, security, ms-office, dde

Good morning,

when I open a file that contain DDE external links, I got a warning advice saying: "This workbook contains links to external data sources that use DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) that may be unsafe and have been disabled. See File > Options > Trust Center for DDE configuration options" Clicking ok and the links seems working good. I'm finding a way to disable showing this warning. Windows 7 Latest Excel version. I have also tried all the google solutions with the (edit links --> startup prompt --> Dont display the alert and update links) advice with no success. Might be the policy of our network admin?

I'm using windows task scheduler to run an excel file with a macro every hour and if this message pops up then it will not be able to run when the file opens.

Any help is appreciated.

-Tim

Answer (score 1):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article says:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You may consider using the Open XML SDK for dealing with open XML documents (.xslx), see  [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.